# transfer permissions user -> group/other

Tags: permissions

How do I transfer write/execute and execute permissions from *owner* to *group* and *other*, respectively?

I have some libraries I want to move to *opt* and set ownership of to *root*. Unfortunately, permissions are a bit messed up for *group* and *other*, and that creates a problem as *group* and *other* cannot use the libraries, call the executables and read the files.

I want to recursively set the permissions of write/execute and execute to *group* and *other* respectively. For example, I want this:

```
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root    4464 Jan 11 23:58 CPackSourceConfig.cmake
-rwxr--r--.   9 root root   28672 Jan 11 23:58 executable
drwxr--r--.   9 root root   28672 Jan 11 23:58 Source
```

to be this:

```
-rw-rw-r--.   1 root root    4464 Jan 11 23:58 CPackSourceConfig.cmake
-rwxrwxr-x.   9 root root   28672 Jan 11 23:58 executable
drwxrwxr-x.   9 root root   28672 Jan 11 23:58 Source
```

How do I best go about doing this, considering there are quite a number of files/folders (recursive)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some mix of find and chmod should do the trick:

- all the directories:

  ```
  find /opt -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
  ```
- all the "executable" files:

  ```
  find /opt -type f -perm -0500 -exec chmod 775 {} \;
  ```
- all the other files:

  ```
  find /opt -type f -not -perm -0500 -exec chmod 664 {} \;
  ```

Comment: Yes it does, due to the "-not" on the "-perm" select option (I  verified the whole case on a BSD box and a RedHat).

Comment: Ah! you're correct. Hadn't parsed the `-` in front of the mode bits. Sorry for the noise :)

Comment: Thanks, It took me a while to decipher the logic behind the two last statements, especially the last one.